# How to get the address of the local service started by stroybook programmatically in the application code?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

When run below npm script, it will start a local server with address `http://localhost:6006`.

```json
"storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
```

I want to get this address in my application code at the top of the `xxx.stories.tsx` file, how can I do this? Maybe I can get the server address from some [environment variable](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/environment-variables) like `STORYBOOK_SERVER_ADDRESS`. But I am not sure.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Story, Meta } from '@storybook/react/types-6-0';
import { Article, ArticleProps } from '../components/Article';
import faker from 'faker';

export default {
  title: 'Example/Article',
  component: Article,
} as Meta;

console.log('get local server address here');
```

package versions:

```json
"@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.1.10",
"@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.1.10",
"@storybook/addon-links": "^6.1.10",
"@storybook/node-logger": "^6.1.10",
"@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.1.5",
"@storybook/react": "^6.1.10",
```

Comment: did you try : window.location.hostname or window.location.href

Comment: @AbuSufian It works. I made the problem complicated. Thanks. I mistakenly think that the `xxx.stories.tsx` code of storybook is not running in the browser environment. In fact, all the code is packaged and run in the browser environment

Comment: welcome. I add my comments as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get whole URL address use:

```
window.location.href
```

To get host name use:

```
window.location.hostname
```